# neo4j - authentication module installation process

Tags: authentication, neo4j

i am trying to install neo4j authentication module but i am not able get the conf/neo4j-server.properties file location and i have read the wiki of the module and i'm confused about the process of adding user with rw and ro.. so please if any one can explain

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

If you installed your server as linux (debian) package the config is in `/etc/neo4j/neo4j-server.properties` and the plugins directory should be in `/var/lib/neo4j/plugins`

Make sure to use the correct version of the authentication extension.

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/authentication-extension/tree/2.0#download-of-precompiled-jars

Comment: currently i am using neo4j in windows

Comment: Hey michael i have a small query can you tell me what is this process called: the process of creation of different users with different authorization right to query the db. i.e. means the loged-in user is only allowed to read from db and not write it. but the user created in backend has the write to manupulate the db

Comment: See the docs: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/authentication-extension#adding-users-with-form-param-userusernamepassword